# Generic way to write an Optimal Control Problem

Tags: optimal-control

I know almost nothing about this field but I see often that optimal control problems are define by an optimization problem like the following

\begin{align}
&\min&\mathcal{J}({x,u,t_0,t_f})\\
&\text{s.t.}&\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t),u(t),t)
\end{align}

where $x$ represent the states, $u$ the controls and $\mathcal{J}$ is a cost function that we would like to minimize to attain our goal.
However, it seems that the equations governing the dynamics could also be a PDE instead of an ODE. Also, there could be some algebraic constraints. I was wondering if there was a nice and concise way to write what it means to have an optimal control problem in whole generality.

Comment: Do you mean *write* where you typed *wright*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, I made a mistake